# sharepoint with JQuery - stops working when click on column filter

Tags: jquery, css, sharepoint, filter, sharepoint-2013

I'm using a code that color the row of an item in a sharepoint list. 
when I'm filtering one of the columns in the list view - the JQuery stops working... what do I need to add to the code or write differently ?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $Text = $("td.ms-cellstyle.ms-vb2:contains('Approved')"); $Text.parent().css("background-color", "#01DF3A");
        $Text = $("td.ms-cellstyle.ms-vb2:contains('Rejected')");
        $Text.parent().css("background-color", "#F90101");
        $Text = $("td.ms-cellstyle.ms-vb2:contains('Pending')");
        $Text.parent().css("background-color", "#EAC117");
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The '$(document).ready' function will only run once on page load.

When you filter you are recreating the HTML elements inside your table. Because of this your jQuery code never runs on these new HTML elements.

You will need to call your function to color the cells by status after you do the filtering as well as on page load.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        colorCellsByStatus();
    });

    var colorCellsByStatus = function() {
        $Text = $("td.ms-cellstyle.ms-vb2:contains('Approved')");
        $Text.parent().css("background-color", "#01DF3A");
        $Text = $("td.ms-cellstyle.ms-vb2:contains('Rejected')");
        $Text.parent().css("background-color", "#F90101");
        $Text = $("td.ms-cellstyle.ms-vb2:contains('Pending')");
        $Text.parent().css("background-color", "#EAC117");
    }
```