# SharePoint 2013 Hyperlinks Made Using J Query Stop Working After Filtering

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, filter, hyperlink, sharepoint-2013

I found the post: [sharepoint with JQuery - stops working when click on column filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24593264/sharepoint-with-jquery-stops-working-when-click-on-column-filter) but couldn't get it to work.

I want to show HTML in the cells of a SharePoint list as hyperlinks. The code I have works until someone tries to filter the list--the element refreshes to show the search results in the SharePoint list and the links revert to the HTML code, rather than clickable links.

I do not have access to the Master Pages or SharePoint Designer. My only options are the OOB Web Parts.

Here is the code I am using:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var textholder = "";
    $("td.ms-vb2:contains('<a href=')").each(function() {
        textholder = $(this).text();
        $(this).html(textholder);
    });
})
</script>
```

What can I add to make the code work on refresh? I am a novice and would appreciate the solution to be inserted in the code as I don't know where I would put in commands. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I used to solve my problem (entered into a Script Editor Web Part):

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function () {
        if (typeof SPClientTemplates === 'undefined')
        return;
        SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({
        OnPostRender: [
          function (ctx) { DoStuff(ctx); },
        ]
      });
      })();

     function DoStuff(ctx) {
    var textholder = "";
    $("td.ms-vb2:contains('<a href=')").each(function() {
        textholder = $(this).text();
        $(this).html(textholder);
    });     }
  $(document).ready(function(){
       var textholder = "";
    $("td.ms-vb2:contains('<a href=')").each(function() {
        textholder = $(this).text();
        $(this).html(textholder);
    }); });
</script>
```